# Why is Numpy Array that has been converted to list with .tolist() and then back to array with numpy.array() not the same as the original Numpy Array?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, numpy-ndarray, pyautogui

I am trying to make a screen monitoring app using databases and python. To upload a screen's data to a database, a screenshot is first taken, then converted into a numpy array. This array has to be in a list format to be sent to the database (due to `json.dumps()` not able to serialize a numpy array). To do this you have to use `numpy_array.tolist()`, then I would send the list to the database. I retrieve the code from the database and convert it back to a numpy array. I then use OpenCV to convert the colors so they are not reversed and resize the image so it doesn't take up the whole screen. The code below is an example test (without sending code to the database).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
# Used to rescale
SCREEN_SIZE = pyautogui.size()
while True:
    # Take a screenshot
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    # Convert screenshot to numpy array
    frame = np.array(img)
    # Convert numpy array to list
    lstframe = frame.tolist()


    # code to send data to database goes here (left out due to it being a test script)

    # code to receive data from database goes here (left out due to it being a test script)


    # Convert list back to numpy array
    npframe = np.asarray(lstframe)
    # Convert the colors from BGR to RGB
    npframe = cv2.cvtColor(npframe, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    # Resize the image so it doesn't take up the entire screen
    framere = cv2.resize(npframe, (int(SCREEN_SIZE[0]/5*4), int(SCREEN_SIZE[1]/5*4)))
    # Show the image
    cv2.imshow("Screen", framere)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, I get an OpenCV error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\s20364\Documents\Python\CommanderV3\screenrecorder.py", line 10, in <module>
    npframe = cv2.cvtColor(npframe, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) d:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.simd_helpers.hpp:94: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::impl::`anonymous-namespace'::CvtHelper<struct cv::impl::`anonymous namespace'::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0x7123906f::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0x7123906f::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 4 (CV_32S)
```

[Yet, when I don't have the conversion to the list and back to numpy array works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfc7B.png):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
# Used to rescale
SCREEN_SIZE = pyautogui.size()
while True:
    # Take a screenshot
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    # Convert screenshot to numpy array
    frame = np.array(img)
    # Convert numpy array to list
    # lstframe = frame.tolist()


    # code to send data to database goes here (left out due to it being a test script)

    # code to receive data from database goes here (left out due to it being a test script)


    # Convert list back to numpy array
    # npframe = np.asarray(lstframe)
    # Convert the colors from BGR to RGB
    npframe = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    # Resize the image so it doesn't take up the entire screen
    framere = cv2.resize(npframe, (int(SCREEN_SIZE[0]/5*4), int(SCREEN_SIZE[1]/5*4)))
    # Show the image
    cv2.imshow("Screen", framere)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: you gotta convert the list to a numpy array *of suitable `dtype`*. use `np.uint8` for the dtype. simply calling `np.asarray`, with no other arguments, will use whatever dtype it feels like, and in your case that seems to have been np.int32

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz well it's not random lol. It'll default to whatever data type is appropriate, using the operating system's default data types. For example, for integers, on Windows, it'll be int32 even on a 64-bit machine -- int64 on Linux.

Comment: OP, none of the code you posted constitutes a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In any case, store the original dtype in a variable and use it when creating the numpy array.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks, using `np.uint8` fixed the issue